# Is there a nice online collaborative handwriting tool?

Tags: gratis, web-apps

Is there a good collaborative handwriting tool that runs online?  A friend and I are working together on a project and would like a place to make handwritten notes together, live.  Ideally the interface is similar to Xournal++, allows us to export the results to PDF, and allows multiple pages, and multiple editors live.  Thanks in advance!